# Numeric keys not working in kCalc

Tags: keyboard, kubuntu

I'm using the latest version of Kubuntu with an a4tech KBS-21 keyboard and there is no problem with my desktop and all the software except for kcalc.
In kcalc, my numeric keys won't work at all while anywhere else they work without any problem.